# Turn off sound at startup

Tags: startup

I am just wondering how to turn off sound at startup? I searched the web, and found a couple of solutions like:

1. Write "`amixer sset Master off`" in `/etc/rc.local`
2. Use `sudo alsactl store`

But neither works.

EDIT: I now realize why the amixer command in rc.local doesn't work. This is because the command executes before the alsa driver is loaded. So one solution is to use (sleep 1; amixer sset Master off) in rc.local.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One way of doing so is using the Ubuntu Tweak tool.  To install it, if you don't have it installed, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the commands below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa 
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak
```

Once it done, type tweak in Dash, and click on the icon.

[image]

When it opens, click on the Tweaks tab, and then Login Settings.

[image]

When that window opens, click on Unlock, and then turn Play Login sound off.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! Does it turn off the sound for all applications (mute the speaker), not just the login sound?

Comment: As per your question, this just turns off the login sound.

Comment: I now realize why the amixer command in rc.local doesn't work. This is because the command executes before the alsa driver is loaded. So one solution is to use (sleep 1; amixer sset Master off) in rc.local. Combined this with your answer, I am now able to completely mute the system.